# Copying a non PNG image to the X clipboard

Tags: shell, xclip

Several questions have already been answered regarding copying images to the X clipboard, and the answer is always to use `xclip` like so:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i image.png
```

This works, but only for PNG files. You might imagine that changing the `-t image/png` to the correct MIME type, such as `image/jpg` or `image/jpeg` for JPEG files, would easily solve the problem, but this simply does not work:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/jpeg -i other_image.jpg
```

The image is copied to the clipboard, but is not recognized by other applications as an image. In my case, copying a JPEG image, Discord refuses to paste any content, while Firefox pastes it as if it was text, resulting in some high quality Unicode soup of random CJK characters.

What is the correct way to copy a non PNG image to the X clipboard using `xclip`?

Comment: The command you suggested seems to output different things depending on what's on the clipboard. When copying a PNG file using `xclip` it shows only `TARGETS` and `image/png`; When copying text from the terminal it shows `TARGETS`, `MULTIPLE`, `UTF8_STRING`, and `STRING`; And when copying an image from Firefox it shows a lot of MIME types, including `image/png` and `image/jpeg`

Comment: for me when i used jpeg file it did not work, but when i used png file, it worked

Answer (score 2):

I think `image/jpeg` format is not supported by `xclip` based on my researches, anyway you always can hack in somewhat, below the solution I found, it will use `convert` to convert the image from jpeg to png and paste the result to the out stream, then pass this stream to xclip in png format so it can copy the image to the clipboard.

```
convert image.jpg png:- | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

Comment: Note that with v7 ImageMagick, that becomes `magick image.jpg png:- | xclip ...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that copying the image to the clipboard is one thing but pasting it into an application, be it Firefox or Chromium, is another thing. I found that it is more efficient to copy the file URI to the clipboard

```
i=/foo/far/img.jpeg
echo "file://$i" | xclip -selection clipboard -t text/uri-list
```

To date I am using the code with chromium and firefox for both .jpg images and small (<25M) .mp4 videos

Answer (score -2):

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png < file_path.png
```

worked for me. But when i used jpeg files it did not work